Tranform incorrect table Excel in correct table Excel
I have problem with my function in Excel,
=LET(filldown;SCAN("";Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!A247;LAMBDA(ini;arr;IF(arr<>"";arr;ini)));DROP(REDUCE("";UNIQUE(filldown);
LAMBDA(u;v;VSTACK(u;HSTACK(INDEX(FILTER(Sheet2!B1:Sheet2!I247;filldown=v);1;SEQUENCE(;4));
IF(INDEX(FILTER(Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!I247;filldown=v);2;2)=0;{""};
INDEX(FILTER(Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!I247;filldown=v);2;2));
DATEVALUE(TEXT(INDEX(FILTER(Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!I247;filldown=v);1;8);"yyyy-MM-dd"))))));1))

its first table:



1
Воробій Сергій Михайлович
Підволочиський районний суд Тернопільської області
51-6905 км 23
Бородій Василь Миколайович
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

19.02.2024






ч. 2 ст.   286-1



Мазур Микола Вікторович

14.00



2
Колодочка Анна Сергіївна
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-1713 км 20
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
Бородій Василь Миколайович

24.01.2024




ч.5 ст.   185



Чистик Андрій Олегович

Жов.30










19.02.2024










Гру.30



3
Гуреєв Максим Олександрович
Слов'янський міськрайонний суд Донецької області
51-2299 км 23
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
Бородій Василь Миколайович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   14, ч. 3 ст. 27, п.п. 11, 12 ч. 2 ст. 115



Чистик Андрій Олегович

12.00



4
Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької   області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

15.11.2023




ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365



Ковтунович Микола Іванович

Жов.30




Франковський   Роман Станіславович





19.02.2024




ч. 2 ст.   121, ч. 2 ст. 365





15.30



5
Макоцей Сергій Григорович
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-5803 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

31.01.2024








Ковтунович   Микола Іванович

Жов.30










19.02.2024










15.15



6
Юдін Дмитро Леонідович
Глобинський районний суд Полтавської області
51-1811 км 23
Ковтунович Микола Іванович
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

17.01.2024




ч. 2 ст.   286-1, ч. 3 ст. 135, ст. 70



Фомін Сергій Борисович

11.00










19.02.2024










12.00



7
Денисенко Тетяна Дмитрівна
Шевченківський районний суд міста Києва
51-5417 зр 23
Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович
Марчук Олександр Петрович

19.02.2024








Яковлєва Світлана Володимирівна

Вер.30




Денисенко   Анатолій Дмитрович





















Зяхор   Михайло Федорович









8
Раку Олександр Андрійович
Октябрський районний суд м. Полтави
51-4973 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   286, ст. 46



Луганський Юрій Миколайович

15.00



9
Дмитришин Сергій Миколайович
Малиновський районний суд м. Одеси
51-5128 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76



Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

14.00




Хоменський   Олександр Миколайович










ч. 1 ст.   14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76










Коваль   Євгеній Євгенійович










ч. 4 ст.   187, ст. 69, ст. 75, ст. 76









10
Анисімов Володимир Олегович
Оболонський районний суд міста Києва
51-6505 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   309



Луганський Юрій Миколайович

15.00



11
Фролов Денис Валерійович
Заводський районний суд м. Запоріжжя
51-4991 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
Бородій Василь Миколайович

17.01.2024




ч. 4 ст.   408, ст. 69



Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

13.00




Дригайло   Тарас Вячеславович





19.02.2024










13.20



12
Бай Володимир Олегович
Солонянський районний суд Дніпропетровської   області
51-6414 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович

19.02.2024




ст. 391



Крет Галина Романівна

13.00



13
Савостін Владлен Миколайович
Баглійський районний суд м. Дніпродзержинська
51-2713 кмо 23
Білик Наталія Володимирівна
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

19.02.2024




ч. 1 ст.   239



Антонюк Наталія Олегівна

12.00








Бущенко Аркадій Петрович










Луганський Юрій Миколайович










Марчук Олександр Петрович










Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович





14
Гальцов Юрій Васильович
Верховний Суд України
51-2450 кмо 21
Луганський Юрій Миколайович
Анісімов Герман Миколайович

29.01.2024




п. 13   ч. 2 ст. 115, ч. 3 ст. 189, ч. 3 ст. 223, ч. 1 ст. 263, ч. 1 ст. 70



Антонюк Наталія Олегівна

11.00








Білик Наталія Володимирівна

19.02.2024








Бущенко Аркадій Петрович

14.00








Марчук Олександр Петрович










Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович






after my function incorrect date in table:



Воробій   Сергій Михайлович
Підволочиський районний суд Тернопільської   області
51-6905 км 23
Бородій Василь Миколайович
ч. 2 ст. 286-1
19.02.2024






Колодочка Анна Сергіївна
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-1713 км 20
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
ч.5 ст. 185
24.01.2024




Гуреєв Максим Олександрович
Слов'янський міськрайонний суд Донецької області
51-2299 км 23
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
ч. 1 ст. 14, ч. 3 ст. 27, п.п. 11, 12 ч. 2 ст. 115
19.02.2024




Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
ч. 2 ст. 121, ч. 2 ст. 365
15.11.2023




Макоцей Сергій Григорович
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-5803 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

31.01.2024




Юдін Дмитро Леонідович
Глобинський районний суд Полтавської області
51-1811 км 23
Ковтунович Микола Іванович
ч. 2 ст. 286-1, ч. 3 ст. 135, ст. 70
17.01.2024




Денисенко Тетяна Дмитрівна
Шевченківський районний суд міста Києва
51-5417 зр 23
Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович

19.02.2024




Раку Олександр Андрійович
Октябрський районний суд м. Полтави
51-4973 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст. 286, ст. 46
19.02.2024




Дмитришин Сергій Миколайович
Малиновський районний суд м. Одеси
51-5128 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст. 14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76
19.02.2024




Анисімов Володимир Олегович
Оболонський районний суд міста Києва
51-6505 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст. 309
19.02.2024




Фролов Денис Валерійович
Заводський районний суд м. Запоріжжя
51-4991 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
ч. 4 ст. 408, ст. 69
17.01.2024




Бай Володимир Олегович
Солонянський районний суд Дніпропетровської області
51-6414 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
ст. 391
19.02.2024




Савостін Владлен Миколайович
Баглійський районний суд м. Дніпродзержинська
51-2713 кмо 23
Білик Наталія Володимирівна
ч. 1 ст. 239
19.02.2024




Гальцов Юрій Васильович
Верховний Суд України
51-2450 кмо 21
Луганський Юрій Миколайович
п. 13 ч. 2 ст. 115, ч. 3 ст. 189, ч. 3 ст. 223, ч. 1 ст. 263, ч. 1 ст. 70
29.01.2024




Шевченко Євгеній Володимирович
Дарницький районний суд міста Києва
51-3076 кмо 23
Луганський Юрій Миколайович
ч. 1 ст. 185, ч. 2 ст. 15 ч. 2 ст. 185
19.02.2024





but i need:



Воробій Сергій   Михайлович
Підволочиський районний суд Тернопільської   області
51-6905 км 23
Бородій Василь Миколайович
ч. 2 ст. 286-1
19.02.2024






Колодочка Анна Сергіївна
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-1713 км 20
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
ч.5 ст. 185
19.02.2024




Гуреєв Максим Олександрович
Слов'янський міськрайонний суд Донецької області
51-2299 км 23
Єремейчук Сергій Володимирович
ч. 1 ст. 14, ч. 3 ст. 27, п.п. 11, 12 ч. 2 ст. 115
19.02.2024




Мокринський Василь Ігорович
Хмельницький міськрайонний суд Хмельницької області
51-4261 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович
ч. 2 ст. 121, ч. 2 ст. 365
19.02.2024




Макоцей Сергій Григорович
Шевченківський районний суд м. Чернівців
51-5803 км 23
Іваненко Ігор Володимирович

19.02.2024




Юдін Дмитро Леонідович
Глобинський районний суд Полтавської області
51-1811 км 23
Ковтунович Микола Іванович
ч. 2 ст. 286-1, ч. 3 ст. 135, ст. 70
19.02.2024




Денисенко Тетяна Дмитрівна
Шевченківський районний суд міста Києва
51-5417 зр 23
Наставний Вячеслав Володимирович

19.02.2024




Раку Олександр Андрійович
Октябрський районний суд м. Полтави
51-4973 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст. 286, ст. 46
19.02.2024




Дмитришин Сергій Миколайович
Малиновський районний суд м. Одеси
51-5128 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст. 14 ч. 5 ст. 185, ст. 198, ст. 75, ст. 76
19.02.2024




Анисімов Володимир Олегович
Оболонський районний суд міста Києва
51-6505 км 23
Фомін Сергій Борисович
ч. 1 ст. 309
19.02.2024




Фролов Денис Валерійович
Заводський районний суд м. Запоріжжя
51-4991 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
ч. 4 ст. 408, ст. 69
19.02.2024




Бай Володимир Олегович
Солонянський районний суд Дніпропетровської області
51-6414 км 23
Чистик Андрій Олегович
ст. 391
19.02.2024




Савостін Владлен Миколайович
Баглійський районний суд м. Дніпродзержинська
51-2713 кмо 23
Білик Наталія Володимирівна
ч. 1 ст. 239
19.02.2024




Гальцов Юрій Васильович
Верховний Суд України
51-2450 кмо 21
Луганський Юрій Миколайович
п. 13 ч. 2 ст. 115, ч. 3 ст. 189, ч. 3 ст. 223, ч. 1 ст. 263, ч. 1 ст. 70
19.02.2024






how i can change my function

What's the goal of your formula?

Change incorrect table to correct

So what does incorrect mean to you? Do you want to fill the gaps with data from above?

Look after using function, created new correct table when take first date, and I need take second date

The new table got all #N/A and #VALUE!  Please give better examples of dummy data (no large dump) and the expected results with that explained.

looks new body please

Does this return the intended result? I'm unsure what you want to return if there isn't a second date for a record. I assume you want to return the second date if there is a second date and that you want to return the first date if there is no second date.
However if there is a third, fourth, fifth date then the formula would return the third, fourth, fifth date.
In the database in the screenshot i've highlighted the records and the second dates if there are second dates.
In your function you have this
Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!A247
which can be shortened a little bit like this
Sheet2!A1:A247
=LET(filldown,SCAN("",A2:A33,LAMBDA(ini,arr,IF(arr<>"",arr,ini))),
DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(filldown),LAMBDA(u,v,
VSTACK(u,
HSTACK(
INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),1,SEQUENCE(,5)),
IF(INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),2,2)=0,
{""},INDEX(FILTER(A2:I33,filldown=v),2,2)),{""},
TEXT(LOOKUP(9^9,FILTER(H2:H33,filldown=v),
FILTER(H2:H33,filldown=v)),"TT.MM.JJJ"),
{""})))),1)  
)


EDIT:
I've updated the formula. Now all dates are returned for each record. Column S which contains the dates is formatted as date.
=LET(rng,A2:I33,
filldown,
SCAN("",CHOOSECOLS(rng,1),
LAMBDA(ini,arr,IF(arr<>"",arr,ini))),
IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(filldown),
LAMBDA(u,v,VSTACK(u,
HSTACK(INDEX(FILTER(rng,filldown=v),1,SEQUENCE(,5)),
IF(INDEX(FILTER(rng,filldown=v),2,2)=0, 
{""},INDEX(FILTER(rng,filldown=v),2,2)),
{""},FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(rng,8),(ISNUMBER(CHOOSECOLS(rng,8)))* 
(filldown=v)),{""})))),1),""))



Yes, if I have 1 date I need take it, if I have 2 take 2, 3=3 etc, if you can help its would be great

I've added a new formula to my answer.

doesnt work , error #REF!

i'm glad it works in my sheet as shown in the screenshot

great, but in my table doesnt work :)

unfortunately i have no idea why it doesn't work in your file.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-ref-error-822c8e46-e610-4d02-bf29-ec4b8c5ff4be     There is a documentation why the #REF! error occurs. Perhaps this is helpful.

I think you mean to get data from the rows where column A contains a numerical value and the price (I think these are amounts?) for the row below that data and summarize them in the same row.
In that case you don't need SCAN and/or REDUCE, simply make use of FILTER:
=LET(x,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(B:G,A:A),1,2,3,4,6),     y,INDEX(B:B,FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A)+1),     z,HSTACK(DROP(x,,-1),y,TAKE(x,,-1)),IF(z="","",z))

x is a filter of the required data from the row containing a numerical value in column A.
y is a filter of the row numbers from column A containing a numerical value. We simply add 1 to the row numbers and use it as the row number for the data in column B.
z simply takes x columns, except the last, stacks y to it and finally stacks the final column of x
This gives your result, but returns 0 for empty prices. Therefore we add: IF(z="","",z) meaning if z is empty, than return a blank, else return the value of z.

no :( please check correct example, cause i dont how i can do it, take first date i can, but second or third etc, i cant

Well you need to explain in words what logic you need applied. With given sample data, and given expected result.

@YuriiAnsiktslos =LET(filldown,SCAN("",A3:A34,LAMBDA(ini,arr,IF(arr<>"",arr,ini))),IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(filldown),LAMBDA(u,v,VSTACK(u,HSTACK(INDEX(FILTER(A3:I34,filldown=v),1,SEQUENCE(,5)),
IF(INDEX(FILTER(A3:I34,filldown=v),2,2)=0,{""},INDEX(FILTER(A3:I34,filldown=v),2,2)),{""},FILTER(H3:H34,(ISNUMBER(H3:H34))*(filldown=v)),{""})))),1),""))

@user22566114 Value error :(

@YuriiAnsiktslos   Perhaps dates are stored as text?

@user22566114 no, dates stored as shortdate

@YuriiAnsiktslos  Screenshot without sensitive data could be helpful.
